# How do I add a class to each element in an array of React Components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

This is my current code:

```js
// src/components/Main.tsx
import * as React from 'react';
import { ReactElement } from 'react';

import * as styles from '../styles/Main.module.scss';

type MainProps = {
  leftBtnGroup: ReactElement[],
  rightBtnGroup: ReactElement[],
  children: string,
};

const Main = ({ leftBtnGroup, rightBtnGroup, children }: MainProps) => (
  <>
    <div className={styles.main__btnBar}>
      <div className={styles.main__btnBar__leftBtnGrp}>
        {
          leftBtnGroup.map((btn) => {
            btn.props.className += ` ${styles.main__btnBar__btn}`;

            return btn;
          })
        }
      </div>
      <div className={styles.main__btnBar__rightBtnGrp}>
        {
          rightBtnGroup.map((btn) => {
            btn.props.className += ` ${styles.main__btnBar__btn}`;

            return btn;
          })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
    {children}
  </>
);

export default Main;
```

Two arrays of components are passed into the `Main` component as input and I want to add a class to each of these components. The function does not know what these components are (i.e. could be buttons, links, divs, or other components) but it can be asserted that they all have a `className` prop. How can I implement this? When I tried the above, I got this linting error:

> ESLint: Assignment to property of function parameter 'btn'.(no-param-reassign)

Comment: If this is for styling, can't you just use a selector such as `.main__btnBar__leftBtnGrp > *`?

Comment: @Altareos That works but I'm trying to avoid using the wildcard as far as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably use `React.cloneElement`( https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement )

```
{
  leftBtnGroup.map(btn => {
    // I used ?? but you can use your choice of checking for existing
    // classes. Without checking, if they have no existing class this
    // would add an 'undefined' class where the existing classes go.
    return React.cloneElement(btn, { className: `${btn.props.className ?? ''} ${styles.main__btnBar__btn}` })
  })
}
```